# How to make sure only one key is pressed

Tags: java, optimization, libgdx, keylistener

SO I'm making a game where the user moves on a horizontal, vertical tiled map. However I dont want the user to be able to press 2 keys and make the player move diagonal. ony left,right,up and down.

I currently have a code that does it but if the user presses another key and then lifts it, the player stops moving due to how I have coded it

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keyNotDown) {
        switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            playScreen.setXD(2);
            break;
        case Keys.LEFT:
            playScreen.setXD(-2);
            break;
        case Keys.DOWN:
            playScreen.setYD(-2);
            break;
        case Keys.UP:
            playScreen.setYD(2);
            break;
        }
        keyNotDown = false;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    player.stopMove();
    keyNotDown = true;
    return false;
}
```

As you can see if a person presses a key while another one is pressed, it will not work but when they lift that said key, then it'll stop moving

EDIT

When the user presses down a key it sends the xd,yD values to the render method and because render keeps being called, it keeps on moving the player with the xD,yD values. The stop move method resets those values to 0 so it stops moving when the key is not being pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normally I don't post a full solution but its fairly simple what you want to do. The solution offers you a different way to implement your design. Since your speed is constant I figure out don't need to set the delta but only change the direction.

You can keep track of the key presses and based on what is pressed you can determine the direction to move your character. So for instance, when you press the up arrow, it sets the direction to up, but when you press left I track it but ignore the button. If you release the up arrow, then your character will move left and at no point will it move in more than 1 direction.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

public class Move implements ApplicationListener {
    private static final Map<Integer, Direction> MOVE_KEYS = new HashMap<Integer, Direction>(){{
        this.put(Keys.RIGHT, Direction.RIGHT);
        this.put(Keys.LEFT, Direction.LEFT);
        this.put(Keys.UP, Direction.UP);
        this.put(Keys.DOWN, Direction.DOWN);
    }};

    private static enum Direction {
        RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN;
    }

    private static class Player {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float speed;
        public Queue<Direction> dirStack = new LinkedList<Direction>();

        public Player(float x, float y, float speed) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public void update(float delta) {
            if (!dirStack.isEmpty()) {
                switch(dirStack.peek()) {
                case DOWN: 
                    y -= speed;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    x -= speed;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    x += speed;
                    break;
                case UP:
                    y += speed;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void render(ShapeRenderer render) {
            render.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
            render.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            render.filledRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            render.end();
        }
    }

    private static class MoveController extends InputAdapter {
        private final Player player;

        public MoveController(Player player) {
            this.player = player;
        }

        @Override public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            if (MOVE_KEYS.containsKey(keycode)) {
                final Direction dir = MOVE_KEYS.get(keycode);
                Gdx.app.log("D", dir.toString());
                return player.dirStack.add(dir);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            if (MOVE_KEYS.containsKey(keycode)) {
                final Direction dir = MOVE_KEYS.get(keycode);
                Gdx.app.log("U", dir.toString());
                return player.dirStack.remove(dir);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Camera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer render;
    private Player player;

    @Override public void create() {
        Gdx.app.log("CREATE", "App Opening");

        this.player = new Player(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 5);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MoveController(player));

        this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        this.render = new ShapeRenderer();

        cam.apply(Gdx.gl10);

        Gdx.gl10.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
    }

    @Override public void render() {
        Gdx.gl10.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        player.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        player.render(render);
    }

    @Override public void dispose() {
        Gdx.app.log("DISPOSE", "App Closing");
    }

    @Override public void resize(final int width, final int height) {
        Gdx.app.log("RESIZE", width + "x" + height);
        Gdx.gl10.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override public void pause() {}

    @Override public void resume() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this following code and let me know, because I haven't test it.

```
private KEY_PRESSE keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.NONE;

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            if (keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.RIGHT) || keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.NONE)) {
                playScreen.setXD(2);
                keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.RIGHT;
                break;
            }
        case Keys.LEFT:
            if (keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.LEFT) || keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.NONE)) {
                playScreen.setXD(-2);
                keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.LEFT;
                break;
            }

        case Keys.DOWN:
            if (keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.DOWN) || keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.NONE)) {
                playScreen.setYD(-2);
                keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.DOWN;
                break;
            }
        case Keys.UP:
            if (keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.UP) || keyPressed.equals(KEY_PRESSE.NONE)) {
                playScreen.setYD(2);
                keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.UP;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        player.stopMove();// I don't know exactly but can you remove this ligne, I
                            // think its useless , when no key is pressed
                            // the player will stop no?
        keyPressed = KEY_PRESSE.NONE;
        return false;
    }

    enum KEY_PRESSE {
        RIGHT, LEFT, DOWN, UP, NONE
    }
```

Comment: when the user presses down a key it sends the xd,yD to the render method so seeing as render keeps being called, it keeps on moving the player with the xD,yD values. the stop move method rests those values to 0

Comment: Unfortunately, it does the same thing

Comment: I think it would be better if you remove stopMove and keep the player pressing the key down if he want to move by playScreen.currentX +=2; can you? and try after that to implement the code

Comment: if i remove the stopMove method, the player literally doesnt stop moving

Comment: I know, but you have to change the way of moving, if the player instance is yours can make changes to the way of playing, you have to keep pressing the key to move not just one click and it move by it self, if its possible make the (big) change otherwise I don't have another idea